# SQL Server 2008 Pagination PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pagination

I am trying to display 10 records per page by using ROW_NUMBER function of SQL SERVER 2008.

I think there is something wrong with my query because I only define where to start and where to end displaying records (from 1 to 10), but not the amount of records displayed per page.

As I go to the next page I get no results displayed at all because I don't know how to add $per_page variable to my SQL query properly.

All I want is be able to display the first 10 product IDs on page 1, and once I click on the "next" button, the next 10 product IDs will be displayed, etc.

This is the code that I have right now:

```
$per_page = 10;

if(!isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $page = 1;
}
else
{
    $page = $_GET['page'];  
}

if($page<=1)
{
    $start = 0;
}
else
{
    $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
}

$tsql = " SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY productID) AS
rownum, productID FROM products) AS products1
WHERE rownum >= $start AND rownum <= $per_page";


$num_rows = sqlsrv_num_rows(sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql));

$num_pages = ceil($num_rows / $per_page); 

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql);
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){ 

            echo $row['productID']. "<br/>";

}


$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;


echo "<hr>";

//prev
if($prev > 0)
{
    echo "<a href='?page=$prev'>prev</a> ";
}

//numbers
$number = 1;
for($number; $number <= $num_pages; $number +=1)
{
    if($page==$number)
    {
        echo " <b>[$number]</b> ";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<a href='?page=$number'>$number</a> ";
    }
}

//next 

    echo "<a href='?page=$next'>next</a>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with sql server, but it seems to me you just need the end point:

```
$tsql = " SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY productID) AS
    rownum, productID FROM products) AS products1
    WHERE rownum >= $start AND rownum < ($start + $per_page)";
                                        ^     changed      ^
```

And if `$page` is supposed to be an integer, it's always best to make sure that it is:

```
$page = (int) $_GET['page'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, jeroen! I am now able to go through all my pages with my "next" and "prev" buttons! The only problem I have now is "numbers" section that I would like to implement as well. My page numbers do not display at all, and I think it has something to do with my $num_pages and $num_rows variables, especially this line: "$num_rows = sqlsrv_num_rows(sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql)); " I followed a mysql pagination tutorial and tried to convert it to SQL server, but I think I made a mistake somewhere in these lines?

Comment: @Alex Like I said, I'm not famil`iar with sql server, but my guess would be that `$num_rows` returns only the number of rows from your query (10), so `$num_pages` will always be 1.